# Add MonthNAME And Number to mysql query

Tags: php, mysql

i running the following query but the problem is i need to add the month name and number to a field name MONTHOFSERVICE in my table, so the imput must show as: 05 May.

now i just getting month name

my  code looks as

```
INSERT INTO clientdocumentation (clientid, DocumentName, Monthofservice,Year, providertype, cname)
SELECT clients.clientid, DocumentName, MONTHNAME(NOW()- INTERVAL 1 MONTH), YEAR(now()), providertype, CONCAT_WS(', ', LastName, Name) AS cname FROM clients, client_docs_templates
END
```

thanks

Comment: Try Printing Your Query While Inserting And Show The Output

Comment: about which number are you talking about?

Answer (score 0):

You can use simple string concatenation and the `MONTH` function to achieve this.

Firstly, this outputs a month number (i.e. `5`):

```
SELECT MONTH(NOW())
```

Presuming from your example you want a two-digit month (i.e. `05`).  This concatenates a leading `0` with the month number and then takes the rightmost two digits:

```
SELECT RIGHT(CONCAT('0', MONTH(NOW())), 2)
```

Now concatenate that with a space and the month name:

```
SELECT CONCAT(RIGHT(CONCAT('0', MONTH(NOW())), 2), ' ', MONTHNAME(NOW()))
```

Outputs:

```
05 May
```

Note: I see in the example that you are subtracting 1 month (therefore April instead of May).  Here's an example showing the same with the subtraction of 1 month:

```
SELECT CONCAT(RIGHT(CONCAT('0', MONTH(NOW() - INTERVAL 1 MONTH)), 2), ' ', MONTHNAME(NOW() - INTERVAL 1 MONTH));
```

Outputs:

```
04 April
```

Comment: i use this way but do not work show error

Comment: INSERT INTO clientdocumentation (clientid, DocumentName, Monthofservice,Year, providertype, cname)
SELECT clients.clientid, DocumentName, CONCAT(RIGHT(CONCAT('0', MONTH(NOW())), 2), ' ', MONTHNAME(NOW() - INTERVAL 1 MONTH)), providertype, CONCAT_WS(', ', LastName, Name) AS cname FROM clients, client_docs_templates
END

Comment: If you run the code `CONCAT(RIGHT(CONCAT('0', MONTH(NOW())), 2), ' ', MONTHNAME(NOW() - INTERVAL 1 MONTH))` you will see that it executes.  The error is elsewhere in your statement

Comment: In fact, you have 6 insert columns and only 5 columns in your select (no YEAR).  That's probably why this doesn't work...

Answer (score 0):

The query you are lokking for is

> ```
> SELECT CONCAT( DATE_FORMAT(NOW()- INTERVAL 1 MONTH,"%m")," ",MONTHNAME(NOW()- INTERVAL 1 MONTH));
> ```
>
> ```
> | CONCAT( DATE_FORMAT(NOW()- INTERVAL 1 MONTH,"%m")," ",MONTHNAME(NOW()- INTERVAL 1 MONTH)) |
> | :---------------------------------------------------------------------------------------- |
> | 04 April                                                                                  |
> ```

*db<>fiddle [here](https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=mysql_5.7&fiddle=f664c3c9224172d22caa1cb9d6a6835b)*

So You complete query would be like

```
INSERT INTO clientdocumentation (clientid, DocumentName, Monthofservice,Year, providertype, cname)
SELECT clients.clientid, DocumentName, CONCAT( DATE_FORMAT(NOW()- INTERVAL 1 MONTH,"%m")," ",MONTHNAME(NOW()- INTERVAL 1 MONTH)) , YEAR(now()), providertype, CONCAT_WS(', ', LastName, Name) AS cname FROM clients, client_docs_templates
```

Comment: OP asked for "_the month name and number_", not the day...

Comment: he didn't specify which number he wants afaik

Comment: "_i running the following query but the problem is i need to add the **month name and number**_".  It's fairly clear what is being asked for

Comment: you wroze it as month name and number  but he wrote monthname and number, so didn't iterprted it as monthnumber

Answer (score -3):

thanks everybody for help , the final code was

```
SELECT clients.clientid, DocumentName, CONCAT( DATE_FORMAT(NOW()- INTERVAL 1 MONTH,"%m")," ",MONTHNAME(NOW()- INTERVAL 1 MONTH)) , YEAR(now()), providertype, CONCAT_WS(', ', LastName, Name) AS cname FROM clients, client_docs_templates
END
```